# how to add user profile picture in flutter local notification

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working on flutter local notification, there's a issues I have no idea when some send message to the another users that time in push notification user profile will be visible.

User profile showup in flutter push notification.

Comment: You want to show the user profile image in the notification, yes??